# How do I incorporate changes I made outside the repo into a repo and then to its remote/origin?

Tags: git, github

I already have some commits to my remote repo.

On a different device i download all the code as zip and start updating it. Now anyway i have to update it to the repo so how should i do that. I am a biggner.
In vs code terminal if i pull `git pull` my changes will go and i will land up with the version i last pushed to github.

Same thing is happening to heroku with these errors

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/priyam.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So how should i push to the remote repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you use git (or any VCS). You really need to take the time to read some beginner tutorials.

What you should have done is use git on that "different device", cloned your repo on it, made your changes, then push them up.

If you moved your changes to the first device (from what you wrote, it sounds like that is what you did but you are not clear), then go ahead and do a `git pull`. Git will attempt to merge the changes on the server with the changes you have in your local repo. This is a core way git manages concurrent changes to code.

If what I wrote confuses you, then again, you really should read some git tutorials. You can't expect to work with something as sophisticated as git without understanding it. Git is NOT known for being beginner friendly. It is a *power* tool. Let me get you started:

- https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=git%20beginner